# Cannot spot the issue with PHP Index error-possible multiple threads issue

Tags: php

I'm struggling to find the problem with the following piece of PHP code:

The code is as follows

```
class WorkerThreads extends Thread
{
  private $from_list;

  public function __construct($x,$host,$users_email,$pass,$inbox)
  {
    $this->from_list = array(); # holds the unique froms extracted from headers
  }

  public function run()
  {
    # Get Froms
    if (preg_match('/From\:\ (.+)/i', $headers, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
      $from = trim(str_ireplace("From: ", "", $matches[0][0]));
      if (!array_key_exists($from, $this->from_list)) {
        $this->from_list[$from] = 1;
        echo "<br/>FROM: ".$from."-".$this->from_list[$from]."<br/><br/>";
      }
    } else {
      echo "NO FROM <br/><rb/>";
    }
```

The following error occurs:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Viva in /var/www/BAMCode/yahoofroms.php on line 198    
FROM: Viva-
```

The offending line 200 is

```
echo "<br/>FROM: ".$from."-".$this->from_list[$from]."<br/><br/>";
```

There seems to be a problem with the array

Comment: So find the line number 198 and check what variable contains the string `Viva` ?

Comment: This is line 198
echo "<br/>FROM: ".$from."-".$this->from_list[$from]."<br/><br/>";

The $from contains Viva - the array for some reason is generating the error...

Comment: So `$this->from_list` doesn't have anything with the key `Viva` then

Comment: Have you initialized `$this->from_list` as array before assigning `$this->from_list[$from]` ?

Comment: Yes - in an earlier function - $this->from_list = array();

Comment: If you created it within a function, it won't be available outside the function. `printr` the array above the line throwing the error

Comment: I've added the code above where it was created - it wasn't created within the function.When I try printing it out, it throws an error...

Comment: Dagon, This isn't a duplicate of that qu - the variable is defined - there is something else going on which relates to multiple threads...

Answer (score -1):

This will work perfectly fine if you don't use multiple threads.

I think many threads are trying to modify  and read the same list. Try synchronizing the modification/read  of the from_list. We may use a mutex to synchronize read/write to the from_list.

Check the code below:

```
<?php
class WorkerThreads extends Thread
{
  private $from_list;
  private $mylock;

  public function __construct($x,$host,$users_email,$pass,$inbox)
  {
    $this->from_list = array(); # holds the unique froms extracted from headers
    $this->mylock = Mutex::create();
  }

  public function __destruct()
  {
    Mutex::destroy($this->mylock);
    $this->mylock = null;
  }

  public function run()
  {
    # Get Froms
    if (preg_match('/From\:\ (.+)/i', $headers, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
      $from = trim(str_ireplace("From: ", "", $matches[0][0]));
      Mutex::lock($this->mylock);
      if (!array_key_exists($from, $this->from_list)) {
        $this->from_list[$from] = 1;
        echo "<br/>FROM: ".$from."-".$this->from_list[$from]."<br/><br/>";
      }
      Mutex::unlock($this->mylock);
    } else {
      echo "NO FROM <br/><rb/>";
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: How would I do that? I'm a little unclear on threading tbh.

Comment: @Del I have updated the answer. You may use a mutex for synchronizing critical sections. Or you may use synchronized block as well.

Comment: I still get the same error nipun as wel as this at the end "Notice: Undefined property: WorkerThreads::$mylock on line 162" where line162 is Mutex::destroy($this->mylock);

Comment: Each new class has it's own set of private vars - I'm not sure we need to use mutex as the various classes are not sharing vars

Comment: Add mylock as a private variable. Check the modified code. Can you paste  the entire program somewhere, may be in ideone.com? Then only it will be clear where the error is.

Comment: Here's the entire code Nipun http://ideone.com/RpfWIp - the problem seems to be the use of arrays in php pthreads... it appears they have to be managed in a different way - locking isn't the issue.